# Apache spark row cast exception from timestamp to date

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a column with `java.sql.timestamp` in Apache Spark. When I extract a row column from `DF`, it gives me Any as its value.

```
val dfv = filterDF.first().get(0);
```

where `DF` is my dataframe.
Now `dfv` is ANY but I know it's a timestamp.  How can I extract timestamp as is into a variable? Is there a way to convert this any to a timestamp or a date?
I used `getDate()` of row but it did not work, saying it's a cast exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you could cast the object:

```
((Timestamp)row.get(0))
```

In Scala you can call asInstanceOf:

```
row.get(0).asInstanceOf[Timestamp]
```

Comment: Well asInstanceOf is not available in spark 1.4, I am using getAs to get the Timestamp. Thanks anyways. marking this as answer

Answer (score 1):

```
row.getTimestamp(0)
```

Just in case someone will look for this in the future.