# How to convert scala.collection.immutable.HashMap to java.util.Map in spark dataset 2.2 in java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset,say DS.

```
DS.printSchema()

root
 |-- BRAND: string (nullable = true) 
 |-- single: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true) 
 |-- PRICE: string (nullable = true)
```

When I tried to iterate DS using map transformation and access single map variable it is throwing Below Error.

```
    DS.map(row -> {

    Map<String, String> singleColMap = row.getAs("single");

    })

Error - 
    java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

Can someone help one on how to access map variable in spark java.

Thanks!.

Comment: Try `getAs[Map[String, String]]("single")` and see if it works

Comment: This is not working in spark java. compile time error.

Comment: Ah, yes. That is Scala syntax, for Java maybe this could give an idea (Timestamp type but the same should apply here): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603848/apache-spark-row-cast-exception-from-timestamp-to-date

Comment: Try using JavaConverters.mapAsJavaMapConverter(_scalaMapObject_).asJava()

[refer link](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html#inner-main)

Comment: `new java.util.HashMap(HashMap[String, String](("s", "s1")).asJava)`